# How to fix unknown error (empty FormData file) uploading image file

Tags: angular, express

If anyone can please help me fix the following code, which is sending empty 'FormData`object to`http/post`, I'd be hugely grateful:

I've looked online for several days, but none of the supposed fixes have worked.

`app.component.html`

```
<input type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" >
<button (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile: File; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    console.log("File name: " + this.selectedFile.name);    
  }

  uploadFiles() {
    let fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    console.log("Uploading: " + JSON.stringify(this.selectedFile.name));
    try {
        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/selection/test-photo",fd)
        .subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log("Successful response: " + res)},
          (err) => {
            console.log("Subscribe error: " + JSON.stringify(err))} 
      );
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log("Caught error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding the backend route `selection_controller.js` in Express, all I'm doing for now is logging the `http.post` request:

```
exports.selection_test_photo = [
    (req,res,next) => {
        console.log("Posting . . . ");
        console.log("Photos: " + util.inspect(req.body));
        res.json(req.body);
    }
];
```

Here is the client screenshot after it runs:

[image]

And server-side logging:

[image]

Comment: Catch errors and tell what you get when you log them. Also please find out the error status. It would be helpful if you can provide a screenshot of the error from your console.

Comment: As per your suggestion, @Arcteezy: caught errors (pls see log at top of orig. post). Also pasted screenshot, and added `error` callback to `http.post` subscription . . . Many thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @Crowdpleasr Can you explain about the backend API as well ? what is expected as request over there

Comment: @Shashank Vivek - As per your suggestion, I added the backend API to the original post (pls see above).

Comment: @Crowdpleasr : I have used experss.js to save `csv` file. I used `multer` for that , are you using something like that ?

Comment: @Crowdpleasr You got an error status of **0**, which means the server you are trying to hit is not found. Make sure the server is running in port 3000. Also try with a curl or postman request to make sure server is there and works fine.

Comment: @Crowdpleasr Is this line should be `http:\\localhost:3000/test-photo` also check with postman

Comment: @Shashank Vivek - I'm not using `multer`, but I'll look into that.

Comment: @Arcteezy - I added cURL result above into original post, so can verify the server is working . . .

Comment: Changed to `http://localhost:3000/test-photo` as per @Prashant Pimpale's suggestion. (Good catch!). Works better, but still getting error (pasting new error into original post).

Comment: Your problem is in the backend. Use multer if your backend is node.js and add all your code because is hard to figure out what is the problem

Comment: @Crowdpleasr : Check out `multer` , if required let me know.. i"ll post the code which I have used to get CSV file data and store it in memory (rather than creating it server filesystem)

Comment: @Crowdpleasr You got **404** i.e. the API you are trying to hit is not found. You made a curl request to **/test** but the API from UI is going to **/test-photo**. Which is correct?

Comment: Tks, @Arcteeezy, `/test` was just to test the server, `/test-photo` is the actual route. It turns out there was a problem with the route, and I fixed it, so now no 404 error, but when I try to inspect the upload file Object on the server (using `util.inspect(req.body)` or `JSON.stringify(req.body)` the object is empty.

Comment: I've fixed the code so that there are now no more errors, but the `FormData` Object is always empty (both on client and server), verified both by logging and inspecting in the debugger. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: When I inspect the `FormData` with `get()` I can see that there is indeed a file there. I will use `multer` on the Express backend and see if I can save the file (but traveling today, so won't have result for another day or so).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. The main thing was that I needed to use `multer` on the back-end, as per @Shashank Vivek's suggestion:

Front-end (Angular):

```
uploadFiles() {
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.selectedFile);
    fd.append('timeStamp', Date.now().toString());
    try {
        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/selection/test-photo",fd)
        // this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/selection/test-photo",this.selectedFile)
        .subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log("Successful result: " + JSON.stringify(res))},
          (err) => {
            console.log("Subscribe error: " + JSON.stringify(err))} 
      );
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log("Caught error: " + e);
    }
  }
```

Backend Data model (Express):

```
var PhotoSchema = new Schema (
    {
        timeStamp: {type: Object},
        photo: {data: Buffer, contentType: String}
    }
)
```

`app.js`

```
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
      return filename;
    },
  }
).single('image'));
```

photo upload route callback function:

```
var fs= require('fs');

exports.selection_test_photo = [
    (req,res,next) => {
        const photo = new Photo();
        photo.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
        photo.photo.contentType = 'image/png';
        photo.timeStamp = {"value": req.body.timeStamp};
        photo.save(function(err){
            if (err) {return next(err)};
            res.json({"foo": "bar"});
        });        
    },
];
```